# Get Certain Rows based on Column Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   Product   Order   Sales   Variable1  Variable2
0   AB12      500     47000    sdf         345
1   AC19      812     89300    sdf         4235
2   AD55      987     23280    wef         sdf
3   ID92      854     96821    sdf2        2342
4   OP23      851     98600    ewt         342

 .....
95  IU84      789     537850
96  OD93      785     218651
```

And I want to get all the rows, including values from all the columns from row(index) 3 whose prodcut is ID92 and till index# 95, whose product is IU84. Plus, I want all the column values until sales, excluding variable1 and variable2.

Here is my current code

```
df_total =pd.Dataframe()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(data_location):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xls") or file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            df_file = pd.read_excel(subdir + '/' +file)
            a = int(df_file[df_file['Product']=="ID92"].index[0])
            b = int(df_file[df_file['Product']=="IU84"].index[0])
            selected = df_file.loc[a:b, :'Sales']

            df_total = pd.concat([selected, df_total], ignore_index=True)
```

But I keep getting an error message saying "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" for these two lines

```
a = int(df_file[df_file['Product']=="ID92"].index[0])
b = int(df_file[df_file['Product']=="IU84"].index[0])
```

I wonder if it is because I'm looping multiple files together. Could anyone please help me with this error?

Comment: Use `.iloc[0]` instead if ,index[0]

Comment: @Andreas then I get another error saying "cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>"

Comment: You can use .loc[] method instead of applying a loop. For that you need to set the product column as the index of the dataframe. After getting the required rows, you can change the index of the dataframe again

Answer (score 0):

If those are the specific rows you need, then:

```
df.loc[3:95,:]
```